# magento 2 proper way of using the events to capture the admin login success and login failure

Tags: magento2, admin, event-observer, adminhtml, admin-user

What are the steps in magento 2 to use the events to capture the admin login success or admin login fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can observe the following events:

- admin user login success: `backend_auth_user_login_success`
- admin user login fail: `backend_auth_user_login_failed`

In a module you can create the following `etc/events.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="backend_auth_user_login_success">
        <observer name="my_custom_login_success_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AdminLoginSucceeded" />
    </event>
    <event name="backend_auth_user_login_failed">
        <observer name="my_custom_login_failed_observer" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AdminLoginFailed" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then you can create the following observers:

- `Observer/AdminLoginSucceeded.php`
- `Observer/AdminLoginFailed.php`