# How to restrict admin user to log in if already any user logged in

Tags: magento-2.1, login, admin-panel, user-roles, admin-user

I know about the feature of `Admin Account Sharing` of magento2. Using this feature if someone login to admin panel from another device then already logged in user get expired session error and logged out automatically.

But I want if any admin user is already login in admin panel and same user or another user try to login in admin panel then user will get message that `any admin user already logged in system`.

So Is there any setting in magento2 for this or any extension for this?

If no then How can I develop my own module to to so?

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can merge up two thing.

First at admin login event you can check weather admin login or not.

for admin login event you can use this event

[magento 2 proper way of using the events to capture the admin login success and login failure](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125718/magento-2-proper-way-of-using-the-events-to-capture-the-admin-login-success-and)

for this you can take reference of this post

[Magento 2 How to check if Admin Logged on frontend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106631/magento-2-how-to-check-if-admin-logged-on-frontend)

by merging up above two post you can get your answer